# How to select distinct table from joined tables with Hibernate Criteria API?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, criteria, hibernate-criteria

I'm trying to implement a query like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT C.* FROM A
join B on A.some_id = B.some_id  
join C on B.some_id = C.some_id;
```

With Hibernate Criteria API.
I need to have distinct results for **whole** C table, not just for some column(s) of it.

I tried to do like that:

```
Criteria criteria = createCriteria(C.class, "ct")
                .createCriteria("B", "bt")
                .createCriteria("A", "at")
                .//Some restrictions which are applied to all tables
```

And like that:

```
Criteria criteria = createCriteria(A.class, "at")
                .createCriteria("B", "bt")
                .createCriteria("C", "ct")
                .//Some restrictions which are applied to all tables
```

(I don't see a difference though).
Tried to ad ResultTransformer:

```
criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
```

Tried to put all colums into ProjectionsList and then:

```
criteria.setProjection(Projections.distinct(projectionList));
```

But that projection only adds "distinct" keyword to first column in list but not to whole table.

What I want to achieve - is something like that:

```
criteria.setProjection(Projections.distinct("C.*"));
```

but I only can add a column here, can't use wildcards like in query.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, there was a mistake in code I provided, I need distinct results from C table.

Comment: Why are you joining to other tables at all then?  Just remove the references to the other tables.

Comment: That's because I need to apply some restrictions to all tables.

Answer (score 0):

You should select columns from table 'C' not from table 'A' like below.

```
SELECT distinct (*) FROM C
```

it can be written in hibernate criteria as follows:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(C.class);
criteria  = criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
ResultTransformer rt = new DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer();
List list = rt.transformList(criteria.list());
```

Comment: I need to write it with Hibernate Criteria API.

Comment: Do you want only columns needed from Table C and not from table A or table B?

Comment: Yes, exactly. And I need it to be distinct on table level.